# Equivalent of explode(), str_replace() in ASP

Tags: php, asp.net

I have a template I am calling from another server.  I have to use some string replaces to fix the URLs, then.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$currentPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$template = file_get_contents("http://staging.domain.edu/content/libs/folder/template.html");
$template = str_replace("src=\"/etc/","src=\"https://dite.edu/etc/",$template);
$template = str_replace("href=\"/etc/","href =\"https://site.edu",$template);
$template = str_replace("src=\"/apps/","src =\"https:site.edu/",$template);
$template = str_replace("href=\"/content/","href =\"http://site.edu/content/",$template);
$template = str_replace("src=\"/content/","src=\"http://staging.domain.edu/content/",$template);
```

then I do this:

```
list($top, $bottom) = explode('INSERT CONTENT HERE', $template);`
```

My question is: how can I duplicate this in asp? All our services except one use PHP, and this one uses ASP.

Comment: thanks, much better question

Comment: @AmalMurali Nice edit, like how you assume this isn't [tag:asp-classic] when the OP hadn't suggested it is [tag:asp.net]. Can the OP please clarify? Either way my answer applies to both.

Comment: @Lankymart: I accidentally removed that tag while removing `explode()` and `str-replace()` tags. Feel free to add it back.

Comment: @AmalMurali Ok, no problem then hopefully my [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4686987) will be approved then.

Comment: @Lankymart: Oh, I guess SE is experiencing some sort of caching issues probably. I tried to add it back, but it showed me "New tag can be edited in unless the pending suggested edit is reviewed". I approved it now :)

Comment: @LisaH by the way do you need equivalent for this part in C# $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$currentPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$template = file_get_contents("http://staging.domain.edu/content/libs/folder/template.html");
 or not?

Comment: Thanks all, see my answer below as to classic or .net . Will have to research more.

Comment: @AllBlond yes, that would be helpful!

Comment: @LisaH Just so I'm clear have you used [tag:asp-classic] before? Not sure we should turn this question into a 101 tutorial in Classic ASP. If you haven't come across the `$_SERVER` equivalent in Classic ASP without sounding condescending I would seriously suggest you read a beginners guide or an online tutorial. I will help you anyway I can in the context of your original question.

Comment: @Lankymart She is all yours. She thinks that it is classic but who knows what vendor supplied to them. It could be C++, MVC, C# or Ruby... I noticed that someone asked about extensions of the files - no answer...

Comment: @AllBlond I'm sure she will answer, just best give her a little time.

Comment: @Lankymart So this is the answer the vendor sent:
"The Web pages are Microsoft.net framework (Classic and Extended) 4.0.  They all have .html extensions. "

Comment: @AllBlond see answer above. I can research this more. We have a completely new website coming up Tuesday... this service is an outlier, and the only one that uses these languages. Maybe I will research more so I can do this better. Thanks!

Comment: @LisaH Well that was a huge waste of my time, cheers for your clear and concise question in the first place.

Comment: @LisaH The only Microsoft NET 4.0 site which uses HTML extension is the one which does not use NET technologies at all. I do not see how any of the answers provided in this node could be used, or PHP solution on this matter. On top of that could someone explain to me what is "Microsoft.net framework (Classic and Extended) 4.0." she is referring to?

Comment: @AllBlond Not sure I understand you, the OP said they are "*.Net*" that is enough for me to just leave this question alone. The fact they have `.html` extension is of no consequence because a HTTPHandler can be mapped to any extension or none at all (`.aspx` isn't exclusive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **IMPORTANT:**
>
> It is [now clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373193/equivalent-of-explode-str-replace-in-asp#comment35854162_23373193) that this question is .Net not [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic) but for anyone who ends up here looking for Classic ASP equivalents of these functions carry on reading.

---

**Classic ASP Equivalent Functions**

There are equivalents for both these functions in Classic ASP

---

`explode()` is used to split a string into an array using another string.
The equivalent in Classic ASP is called (funnily enough) `Split()` and can be used like so;

```vb
Dim list, template
'This will give you a list array variable containing the array elements from the Split().
list = Split(template, "INSERT CONTENT HERE")
```

---

`str_replace()` is used to replace occurrences of a search string inside another.
The equivalent in Classic ASP is called (bet you can't guess) `Replace()` and can be use like so;

```vb
Dim template
template = Replace(template, "src=""content""", "src=""http://staging.domain.edu/content/""")
```

Comment: @LisaH If you're using .NET this doesn't apply this is Classic ASP using VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if question actually need answer for Classic ASP or C# because syntax is different in Classic ASP  then for C#. OP must be more specific where she/he is going to use answers. Your PHP Equivalent of explode(), str_replace() in C# would be

```
 string[] list;
 string NewTemplate;


    template.Replace("src=\"/etc/","src=\"https://dite.edu/etc/", "What ever your replacement should be");
    // repeat this as many times as you want to or you can use it like 
    // NewTemplate= ((Source.replace(a,b)).replace(c,d)).replace.... and so on
    // list=NewTemplate.split......
 list = template.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

where stringSeparators is your 'INSERT CONTENT HERE'

Comment: Good point some clarity on what they are using would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is classic. I say this because it is vendor supplied, I just need to populate the look and feel with a template. I tried researching what they use (manuals are scant), but couldnt find. I will try some more though. Thanks.

Comment: @LisaH Agreed with Lankymart,  If you post actual code to one you trying to convert your PHP to it will help to provide you with better answer. Because right now it is everybody guess what exactly do you need and your tag include both C# and Classic ASP. At least what extensions files are using - xxx.ASP or xxx.ASPX/ xxx.CS?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.net, you may use this to achieve your goal:

```
REPLACE(ORIGINSTRING,TEXTTOMATCH,REPLACETEXT)
```

Assume that you have a string in a variable named `T` with the following text `I'M A SHINY BOY` and you want to change `BOY` to `GIRL`:

```
REPLACE(T,"BOY","GIRL")
```

Done!

About the second statement, I suppose it is some sort of iteration but I've never seen it before so I can't add more information.

Comment: You mean you've answered and you don't know? Ofc it is an iteration you can even define how many times to replace, by default though it finds all occurrences.

Comment: No I know about str_replace but i never seen befor list($top,$bottom) i don't know how it work

Comment: Misunderstood, when you said second statement assumed you were referring to "your" second statement in your answer. The `list($top, $bottom)` is simply two defined elements of an array and `explode()` is used to populate them. The function `Split()` gives similar functionality but it is dynamic and number of elements returned depends of the string used to split the original string that is passed.